# Can iOS Swift play two separate audio files out of two separate pairs of AirPods?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I've been trying to play two different audio files out of two different pairs of AirPods simultaneously from a Swift app. After some trial and error, I've come to the following roadblock:

- There can only be one AVAudioSession
- The only way for an AVAudioSession have AVAudioPlayers playing out of different output devices is by setting its category to [multiRoute](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/category/1616484-multiroute)
- The only way for an AVAudioSession to detect "A2DP" devices for output (such as AirPods) is to set the category option [allowBluetoothA2DP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1771735-allowbluetootha2dp)
- The multiRoute category does not allow for the allowBluetoothA2DP option

Therefore, I feel I am stuck. Is there something I'm missing?

I tried detecting my bluetooth AirPods with a multiRoute AVAudioSession, with no success. I tried adding the allowBluetoothA2DP option to the multiRoute category, and the app crashed.

Comment: have you managed to pair two pairs of AirPods to your device at the same time?